# Preserving DropDownList settings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage: **Menu.aspx**, where I have the following controls of relevance:

- a DropDownList with some values
- a button, which redirects me to a page called Edit.aspx.

In my **Edit.aspx** page, I have a cancel button, which redirects the user back to the Menu page with the following C# method

```
protected void btnCancel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx");
}
```

What I would like to do is when I redirect my user back to Menu.aspx, I preserve the value of the DropDownList that they selected.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ideally, I want to achieve this without a QueryString (if Possible)

EDIT2: I was thinking of something invovling a viewstate or postback but I'm unfamiliar with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called `Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx");` you were already making a new request which the previous page was not part. It's like calling the page anew.

You can put the value in session before coming to Edit.aspx or pass the value back through query string

```
 Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx?dropdownvalue=123");
```

On `Menu.aspx`, you'll check if `?dropdownvalue=123` exist and you set selected item to that value

Comment: Ideally I want to do this without the usage of a querystring, but that was the solution that I was originally thinking of

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'll go with a query string. It seems to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the most ellegant solution, but you can create a session variable containing the selected value.

For example:

```
dropDown_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["SelectedItem"] = dropDown.SelectedValue;
}
```

When you do the redirect, on the page load of the Menu.aspx, after you populate the DropDown, check if this session variable exists, then select the item and remove it from the application.

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         //populate drop down here

         if(Session["SelectedItem"] != null)
         {
              dropDown.SelectedValue = Session["SelectedItem"].ToString();
              Session["SelectedItem"] = null;
         }
   }
}
```

Or you can pass it via query string, but this way you preserve you url