# ASP Query String From DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage: **Menu.aspx**, where I have the following controls of relevance:

- a DropDownList with some values
- a hyperlink, which redirects me to a page called Edit.aspx.

In my **Edit.aspx** page, I have a cancel button, which redirects the user back to the Menu page

What I would like to do is when my user clicks on the hyperlink to go to the Edit page,index of the DropDownList is preserved in a query string In my ***Menu.aspx*** page I have the following aspx code, but I am not sure how to proceed

```
<asp:HyperLink
    ID="lnkEdit"
    NavigateUrl='<%# "Edit.aspx?" + Eval("UserID") + ...not sure... %>'
</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:DropDownList
    ID="myDropDown"
    ...some <asp:ListItems/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

EDIT: Clarified why Im using NavigateURL. Because my query string already does an Eval to determine the user ID.

Comment: So your ultimate goal would be to redirect the user to a page like `Edit.aspx?userID=1&DropDownValue=value`? @RoyiNamir is right, you'll have to use javascript.

Comment: so why your question isnt tagge with js ? :-)

Comment: or you could use an edit "button", which would submit the page. The button click event can do what you want - redirect the user to Edit.aspx?user=userId&menu=selectedValue... or just autopostback with the ddl

Comment: So can I do something like this:

    NavigateURL="return getURL()" where getURL is a JS function?

Comment: @Rhs, seems that your hyperlink is in a databound control?

Comment: ... this was pretty much answered already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295937/preserving-dropdownlist-settings. although i guess its that your edit page doesn't know what you're supposed to be editing.

Comment: @Kudan Singh Chouhan I have multiple hyperlinks within a grid.

Comment: @Rhs are we talking about grid  items here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `LinkButton` control with a server-side `OnClick` event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn1" runat="server" OnClick="lbtn1_Click" 
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' />
```

Server side method:

```
public void lbtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
    string userID = lbtn.CommandArgument;
    string dropDownValue = myDropDown.SelectedValue;
    string navigateUrl = string.Format("Edit.aspx?userid={0}&dropdown={1}", 
        userID, dropDownValue);
    Response.Redirect(navigateUrl);
}
```

EDIT: As Royi Namir points out below, javascript is a better option if you can use that. This creates an unnecessary round trip to the server.

Comment: why do you round trip to server just for such a simple scenario ?

Comment: It didn't seem like he wanted to use javascript as I was writing this. I agree with you though, JS is definitely a better option than this round trip.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way is to use Session

**Example:**

```
Session["SessionName"] = idDropDownList;
```

On another page, access only the content of the session

```
string idDropDownList = (string)Session["SessionName"];
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit"
    NavigateUrl='<%# "Edit.aspx?" + Eval("UserID") + 
    "&menuid=" + myDropDown.SelectedValue %>'> MyText </asp:HyperLink>
```

and also set `AutoPostBack` to true on your drop down. Whenever you will change your dropdown, new selected value bind with hyperlink navigate url.

Comment: That looks really good. I'll let you know how it goes. But I may be leaning towards changing the HyperLink into a LinkButton and making an OnClientClick feature

Comment: That won't do what you want it to do. Those arguments are going to be evaluated when the asp:Hyperlink gets served up to the browser as an anchor tag... so the navigate URL will not reflect a changed selected value. Also, if you are using OnClientClick then there is no need to change from hyperlink to linkbutton.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I made an OnClientClick for my hyperlink with a JS function that does an alertbox and nothing happens. Did the same thing for a linkbutton and it worked. HyperLink doesn't have an OnClientClick

Comment: yes but you can do the same thing by just giving it an onclick event like onclick="alert('boo')".  and the example above would work since it has autopostback... but rebuilding the page just to set the value of that hyperlink isn't very efficient so the onclick event is better.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Yeah you are right. I'm going to go with that route